# How to refresh Embedded PowerBI in MVC(C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerbi-embedded

**Reference**: [PowerBI Developer Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples)

We have created a report using PowerBI and using Azure. I have added the workspace, reportid etc. and the report displays. But I need the report to update every time the page is loaded(i.e. a user refreshes the page, or clicks on the link to redirect to the page where the report is).

I have searched and see you can set scheduled refresh, but that wont work, it needs to be more real-time. Is there a way to refresh the report the way I want to as specified above ?

Below is whats in my controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Dashboard(string username = null, string roles = null)
        {
            var result = new EmbedConfig();
            try
            {
                result = new EmbedConfig { Username = username, Roles = roles };
                var error = GetWebConfigErrors();
                if (error != null)
                {
                    result.ErrorMessage = error;
                    return View(result);
                }

                // Create a user password cradentials.
                var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);

                // Authenticate using created credentials
                var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
                var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ApplicationId, credential);

                if (authenticationResult == null)
                {
                    result.ErrorMessage = "Authentication Failed.";
                    return View(result);
                }

                var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

                // Create a Power BI Client object. It will be used to call Power BI APIs.
                using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
                {
                    // Get a list of reports.
                    var reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId);

                    // No reports retrieved for the given workspace.
                    if (reports.Value.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        result.ErrorMessage = "No reports were found in the workspace";
                        return View(result);
                    }

                    Report report;
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReportId))
                    {
                        // Get the first report in the workspace.
                        report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == ReportId);
                    }

                    if (report == null)
                    {
                        result.ErrorMessage = "No report with the given ID was found in the workspace. Make sure ReportId is valid.";
                        return View(result);
                    }

                    //refreshDataset(ReportId, report.DatasetId, tokenCredentials);

                    var datasets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, report.DatasetId);
                    result.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired = datasets.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired;
                    result.IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired = datasets.IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired;
                    GenerateTokenRequest generateTokenRequestParameters;
                    // This is how you create embed token with effective identities
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
                    {
                        var rls = new EffectiveIdentity(username, new List<string> { report.DatasetId });
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(roles))
                        {
                            var rolesList = new List<string>();
                            rolesList.AddRange(roles.Split(','));
                            rls.Roles = rolesList;
                        }
                        // Generate Embed Token with effective identities.
                        generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view", identities: new List<EffectiveIdentity> { rls });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Generate Embed Token for reports without effective identities.
                        generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
                    }

                    var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(WorkspaceId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

                    if (tokenResponse == null)
                    {
                        result.ErrorMessage = "Failed to generate embed token.";
                        return View(result);
                    }

                    // Generate Embed Configuration.
                    result.EmbedToken = tokenResponse;
                    result.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
                    result.Id = report.Id;

                    return View(result);
                }
            }
            catch (HttpOperationException exc)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Status: {0} ({1})\r\nResponse: {2}\r\nRequestId: {3}", exc.Response.StatusCode, (int)exc.Response.StatusCode, exc.Response.Content, exc.Response.Headers["RequestId"].FirstOrDefault());
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = exc.ToString();
            }

            return View(result);
        }
```

Below is the Javascript being used to create the report:

```
<script>
        window.onload = function () {
            //Creating breadcrumbs
            $('#ribbon ol').empty();
            $('#ribbon ol').append('<li>Dashboard</li>');
        }

        // Read embed application token from Model
        var accessToken = "@Model.EmbedToken.Token";

        // Read embed URL from Model
        var embedUrl = "@Html.Raw(Model.EmbedUrl)";

        // Read report Id from Model
        var embedReportId = "@Model.Id";

        // Get models. models contains enums that can be used.
        var models = window['powerbi-client'].models;

        // Embed configuration used to describe the what and how to embed.
        // This object is used when calling powerbi.embed.
        // This also includes settings and options such as filters.
        // You can find more information at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details.
        var config = {
            type: 'report',
            tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
            accessToken: accessToken,
            embedUrl: embedUrl,
            id: embedReportId,
            permissions: models.Permissions.All,
            settings: {
                filterPaneEnabled: false,
                navContentPaneEnabled: false
            }
        };

        // Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
        var reportContainer = $('#reportContainer')[0];

        // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
        var report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which mode is your report - Direct Query or Imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your report is, as asked by Andrey, Direct Query, then you can call [report.refresh()](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding---Basic-interactions#refresh-a-report) on your embedded report in the JavaScript. The difference between Direct Query and Imported is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-about).

Comment: Thanks for this info. It seems the reports are using Imported Mode. My colleague said he will try make the change to use direct query. Once this is done I will try your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks for pointing this out.